# AWS SDK for PHP wont run when in a different folder to the PHP file

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-web-services

Bashing my head against a wall here - was wondering if anybody could help me out.

My web root directory is `/var/www/`

I have the AWS SDK for PHP installed into `/var/www/aws/`

I have this line in my php.ini file: `include_path="/var/www/aws/;"`

First php file is saved here: `/var/www/aws/` and contains:

```
include('sdk.class.php');
$s3=new AmazonS3();
```

Second php file is saved here: `/var/www/` and contains:

```
include('aws/sdk.class.php');
$s3=new AmazonS3();
```

The first file works, the second file does not. Can anyone tell me how to get the second file to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have `/var/www/aws/` set to `include_path`, for your second PHP file, you should be able to simply:

```
include('sdk.class.php');
```

just like the first one.